# function getNickname() is used but not declared in review module

Tags: magento2

I've tried to modify the reviews. I found that there's a small piece of code `$_review->getNickname()`. I was curious and tried to find that function in order to see how it works.

However, the only files that contain a function with the name are in the zendframework and I highly doubt that ZF provides functions to get review's nicknames.

```
$ grep -rl "function getNickname" 
vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Gdata/Gapps.php
vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Gdata/Gapps/NicknameEntry.php
vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Gdata/Gapps/NicknameQuery.php
```

Where can I find the *correct* `getNickname()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upto M2.1.5, **Review** module has no **Api**. So CRUD operation is done by model/ResourceModel class. When **$review->load()** call it load all related info from **review_detail** table.

Check following file **Magento/Review/Model/ResourceModel/Review.php**

```
/**
 * Retrieve select object for load object data
 *
 * @param string $field
 * @param mixed $value
 * @param AbstractModel $object
 * @return \Magento\Framework\DB\Select
 */
protected function _getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object)
{
    $select = parent::_getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object);
    $select->join(
        $this->_reviewDetailTable,
        $this->getMainTable() . ".review_id = {$this->_reviewDetailTable}.review_id"
    );
    return $select;
}
```

So you can use all **review_detail** table data using M1 way. That means call $review->getNickname() [**nickname is column name**]. Magento magic method automatically return nickname column value.

[Updated]

**Could you make an example on how to get customer_id, please?**

```
$review->getCustomerId();
```

Comment: Could you make an example on how to get `customer_id`, please?

Comment: Check updated answer

Answer (score 3):

> **getNickname()** is not actual function which is define/declare in some file.

But here they have called collection of review model and as your know from model collection we can directly get database field using object of that collection.

So here **nickname** is field of "**review_detail**" table which is called via collection $_review->getNickname();

In list.phtml file if you have seen first line which is -   **$_items = $block->getReviewsCollection()->getItems();**

So here getting collection of items to $_items variable and then iterate that variable data by foreach loop through $_review .

So after that you can directly called nickname via **$_review->getNickname();**